# How does the YouTube player get the image for the search bar?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

When you hover the mouse on the search bar in the player, an image of the current frame is displayed. No XHR requests are sent at this moment. How does the player get this image?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Once you post the cursor over the progress bar, you'll get a image from the current displaying frame.

This is due is made a request

This is an example of the video called "[My bad experience in India and my advices for travelers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wkw-Bfg1Fio)" once I passed the cursor over the progress bar at apporximately "19:10":

[image: M4 image - sample]

You see that there are a few frames that covers the duration once you hover the cursor over the mentioned time.

The url of the given imageis this:

```
https://i9.ytimg.com/sb/Wkw-Bfg1Fio/storyboard3_L2/M4.jpg?sqp=ovOX_wMGCIbK-9UF&sigh=rs%24AOn4CLAKP9a1L-qPaTpNLVtiq8XeTpKHlw
```

I'd read at [this answer in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341591/4092887) that *(if I understand correctly)* basically the parameters in the string of the URL image is used for set the size of the frame and set the frame in the specific time.

You can check the linked answer for get more information.